# How can I highlight a top level dashboard menu item created for a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, add-menu-page

I've used `add_menu_page()` to create a top-level dashboard menu item for a custom taxonomy.  This is due to some specific needs with respect to this plugin.  The menu item works fine, but when you click it, the Posts menu opens.  I've tried to hook the `parent_file` filter to change that and the best I've been able to accomplish is to ensure that no menu appears.

```
add_action("admin_menu", "add_bureau_menu_item");
add_filter("parent_file", "fix_bureau_tax_parent");

public function add_bureau_menu_item() {
    $tax = get_taxonomy("bureau");
    add_menu_page("Bureaus", "Bureaus", "read", "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=" . $tax->name, "", "", 20);
}

public function fix_bureau_tax_parent($parent="") {
    global $pagenow;
    $tax = get_taxonomy("bureau");
    if(!empty($_GET["taxonomy"]) && $_GET["taxonomy"]==$tax->name && $pagenow=="edit-tags.php") $parent = "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=" . $tax->name;
    return $parent;
}
```

So, here's the question:  is there a way to highlight a menu item created with `add_menu_page()` using the `parent_file` filter?

Comment: Will do.  Sorry for the extra work.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Nope.  I never got a response.  When clients have needed it, I tend to use jQuery to add the appropriate class to the menu items.  And, it's usually fairly easy to add that script only on the pages which need it so I figure it's not the worst way to go.